# What will happen with POSIX multithreading with the new C and C++ standards?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, posix

Now that C has also included multi threaded programming in its language with the ISO review, will people still use POSIX for multi threaded programming? Is there any use in it?

Comment: Just for my information, do you have a link to this review?

Comment: Is your question really "What will people do in the future?" I'm not sure that's a suitable SO question.

Comment: Huge amounts of existing code combined with a long lead time before compiler support is available, tested, certified and trusted means that the POSIX thread API will likely be in use for a very long time.

Comment: @fge: From [WG14](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/): "News 2011-12-19: [New revision of ISO/IEC 9899:2011 C standard (C11) published](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=57853)" --- also you can download a [free PDF with the working draft of C11](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf)

Comment: I just broke my crystal ball? wait till i get it repaired.

Comment: I was hoping for a discussion to arise, to get some insight in the possible advantages of pthreads over the new system, etc. Not to get exact details in to what will happen, but perhaps there was a clear future.

Comment: @codd: This isn't a discussion site. If you are hoping for a discussion to arise, then you should try a site that is a discussion forum.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a "discussion" site. That's mentioned explicitly in the close explanation. All questions here need to involve actual problems to solve and have definitive answers. The [faq] contains more details.

Comment: Actually the last draft before the official version is [n1570.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's way too much code out there using pthreads for it to just disappear overnight.  And regardless of what the standards say, threading will only be supported *if compilers implement it*.  Considering the state of things, it'll probably be 5 years or more before "standard threads" or whatever are ready to replace pthreads.  And even then, you'll have some holdouts who don't want to learn new stuff, or still have a compiler from 2005, or...

Short version: pthreads won't be going anywhere anytime soon.